# insert output of sed to another file in between of pattern

Tags: shell, sed

I have to replace some content from one file1 to file2 inside one pattern
file1

```
/* start */
    abc
/* end */
```

file2

```
/* start */
    xyz
/* end */
```

result should be in file2

```
/* start */
    abc
/* end */
```

what I did to achieve this is below:

```
sed -n "/start/,/end/p" file1 >> sed -i 's/start.*end/start  end/g' file2
```

But the above is appending in file2. Please guide

Comment: thanks for showing efforts in your post. Also try to select a answer out of many answers for your post as correct one(after sometime of your post) so that we could consider thread as completed too, cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change lines between string start to end from Input_file1 to Input_file2 then following may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if($0 ~ /^\/\* start \*\//){flag=1;next};if($0 ~ /\/\* end \*\//){flag=""};if(flag){val=val?val ORS $0:$0};next} /^\/\* start \*\//{flag2=1;print;next} /\/\* end \*\//{flag2=""} flag2{$0=val;flag2=""} 1'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0 ~ /^\/\* start \*\//){
     flag=1;
     next};
  if($0 ~ /\/\* end \*\//){
     flag=""};
  if(flag){
     val=val?val ORS $0:$0};
  next
}
/^\/\* start \*\//{
  flag2=1;
  print;
  next}
/\/\* end \*\//{
  flag2=""}
flag2{
  $0=val;
  flag2=""
}
1'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file2 itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file2` in above code's last line too.

Answer (score 1):

You want the lines from file2 until `/start/`, next the lines from file1 between the markers and finally the resulting lines from file 2.
When you ignore the boundaries, this would be

```
(
   sed -n "1,/start/p" file2
   sed -n "/start/,/end/p" file1
   sed -n "/end/,$ p" file2
) > /tmp/outputfile
```

Boundary problems are the double start/stop tags and what will happen when file2 starts with `/start/` or ends with `/end/`.
You can fix the boundary problems with

```
(
   sed "/start/,$ d" file2
   sed -n "/start/,/end/p" file1
   sed "1,/end/ d" file2
) > /tmp/outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/p' file1 |
sed -e '/start/,/end/{/end/r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' file2
```

Pipe the output between `start` and `end` of the first file to stdout. Delete all lines between `start` and `end` in the second file, replacing them by the contents of stdin on encountering `end`.